# Access dynamic second-level property in Typescript object

Tags: typescript, types

I need to access an object property in Typescript for which two levels are dynamic, e.g. object[key1][key2].
Even though I believe I do the appropriate checks, I still get a type error.
(object[key1] as any)[key2] works but doesn't seem very elegant.

Is there a better way? Would really appreciate an idea.

Below the code + playground.

```
const POIs = {
  amenity: {
    bar: {
      activity: "night",
      icon: "glass"
    }
  },
  building: {
    supermarket: {
      activiy: "day",
      icon: "warehouse"
    }
  }
}

interface noiseData {
  tags: {
    [T in keyof typeof POIs]: keyof typeof POIs[T]
  }
}


function parseNoiseSources(nss: noiseData[]): void {
  for (const ns of nss) {
    for (const category in POIs) {
      const cat = category as keyof typeof POIs
      const key = ns.tags[cat]
      if (cat in ns) {
        const obj = POIs[cat]
        if (key in obj) {
          const act = POIs[cat][key].activity
          // Below satisfies the compiler but seems redundant
          // const bct = (POIs[cat] as any)[key].activity
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

**The exact error message is this:**
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"bar" | "supermarket"' can't be used to index type '{ bar: { activity: string; icon: string; }; } | { supermarket: { activiy: string; icon: string; }; }'.
Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ bar: { activity: string; icon: string; }; } | { supermarket: { activiy: string; icon: string; }; }'.

**Playground:**
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBACgeQJIRgXhgbwFAxgQwFsBTMASygE8AuLXPGAI3wCdacGH9goyA3CjRgAicgHMAFlGEAaepzKgwtYWIA2+CBGHyYAX3p65eRgFcyagCZkwY9roimADsRaFWAa2JR7nPN14BIWFLfEpZXTxFcBUAd1ZiCRBTCGIdTgM8AwNsGyhXADNuYhgwEDJUgBF8KHw6PFqxCF8GAG0AFRgbGC9KEAKYKhd++GQIAF1aXpGh4hHEFA7xw2wc7ALTMB4ycBgnVlSAOXLUgGVklmBiCAAKSGbSk+Jq2tbxgEpaPnLLepgCkAsGA3JTQUqoEb3d5-PAAoEg8Bg4A1YhiQGULpgUYoaEcPyg2DI2AYImo9EEVDTAazeZjSIwAk9YgYjCQAB0jQgrSJyz8XQGIJqmPBuPpeEZIEYACt0NiuTyxfzgb1hZKpaK+ZxGQFZQt5TVxq1euM2QF+IJFXgAPRWmAAIWIahAsRgEBqFQKZGugwkJVAhCcFlcTFMsFSxEIqBYxEsm1CYCglpgNoZiNgjB4spueu5BopBDAlHeRuZJrNAioisyfmrWUMeFWQA

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add type for your POIs object:

```js
interface DataFrame {
  activity: string;
  icon: string;
}
type Keys = 'amenity' | 'building'
type Data = Record<Keys, Record<string, DataFrame>>


const POIs: Data = {
  amenity: {
    bar: {
      activity: "night",
      icon: "glass"
    }
  },
  building: {
    supermarket: {
      activity: "day",
      icon: "warehouse"
    }
  }
}

interface noiseData {
  tags: {
    [T in keyof typeof POIs]: keyof typeof POIs[T]
  }
}


function parseNoiseSources(nss: noiseData[]): void {
  for (const ns of nss) {
    for (const category in POIs) {
      const cat = category as keyof typeof POIs
      const key = ns.tags[cat]
      if (cat in ns) {
        const obj = POIs[cat]
        if (key in obj) {
          const act = POIs[cat][key].activity // no error
          // Below satisfies the compiler but seems redundant
          // const bct = (POIs[cat] as any)[key].activity
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`bar` and `supermarket` objects should have same types